# Creat a memory leak with Objective-C and Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-leaks, objective-c-runtime

I had an interview, and I was asked to create a memory leak with Objective-C and Swift.So how to create a memory leak with Objective-C and Swift?

Comment: Just go throught the link about how to create a memory leak and how to avoid memory leak  https://www.raywenderlich.com/134411/arc-memory-management-swift

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to create a reference cycle.
Obj-C:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (strong) MyClass *otherObject;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@end

//...

MyClass *a = [MyClass new];
MyClass *b = [MyClass new];
a.otherObject = b;
b.otherObject = a;
```

The same applies to Swift:

```
class MyClass {
    var otherObject: MyClass?
}

let a = MyClass()
let b = MyClass()
a.otherObject = b
b.otherObject = a
```

**Reason**: `a` holds a strong reference to `b`, and `b` holds a strong reference to `a`. ARC doesn't have any garbage collection in runtime. It just tracks the reference count. In this situation, even if we don't have any references to `a` or `b` in code, their reference count will never reach `0`, since they reference each other (unless we'll break this cycle manually).

**UPD** (kudos to @Sulthan): you don't actually even need two objects, a strong self reference is enough:

```
a.otherObject = a
```

Comment: If you want a minimal example, you can just assign `a.otherObject = a`.

Comment: True answer.I think strong refrence in block may also cause memory leak?But sometimes the complier warns me about the memory leak in block,sometimes not,I was confused then.

Comment: @HensonFang It can but that's just a more complicated instance of this example.

Comment: @HensonFang, yes, in some cases. If you're using GCD, then, most likely, everything will be fine, since GCD doesn't store a reference to your object. But if, for instance, you have an `NSOperationQueue`, and you create an operation with block, that references `self`, then your `self` has a reference to queue, the queue has a reference to operation, operation to block, and block to self.

Comment: Good answer.  I tossed a block example in for kicks.

Answer (score 2):

The block example:

```
@interface Foo:NSObject
@property(strong, copy) dispatch_block_t block;
- (void)doTheMagic;
@end

...
Foo *f = [Foo new];
f.block = ^{
   [f doTheMagic];
};
```

The fix:

```
Foo *f = [Foo new];
__weak typeof(f) __weakF = f;
f.block = ^{
   // you can do the __strong dance here if you use __weakF more than once
   [__weakF doTheMagic];
};
```

The malloc example:

```
void leakVampires() {
    void *buffy = malloc(42);
 }

  ...
 leakVampires();
```

Answer (score -1):

If CGImageRef objected created and not released, then ARC can't release these objects.

Comment: i think that would be automatically released when the viewcontroller dealloc.