# Memory Leak using Objective C Framework in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-leaks

I use [iovation](https://github.com/iovation) framework in my current swift project and I created a bridging header to be able to use it.

I have a `struct` instantiated in view controller and inside of the struct, I have a `String` which receives an iovation `String!` called `ioBegin()`
[image]
The `ioBegin()` is a class method and looks like this in framework:

[image]

When I started using Debug Memory Graph to find Leaks of memory I had this result (I had the same result using Instruments):

[image]

I tried to use `class` instead of `struct` just because I found some explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406196/swift-struct-memory-leak).
I tried to use NSString (reference type) instead of String (value type) for `deviceSig` and I changed the LoginData from `struct` to `class` and my class looked like:

```
class LoginData: NSObject { ... }
```

Whatever I tried it didn't work. The `iovation.ioBegin()` is always seen as `String!`. I don't know what else I should try.

A similar question with the current one should be: [Creat a memory leak with Objective-C and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994146/creat-a-memory-leak-with-objective-c-and-swift) but it doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your memory graph is not rising, and if there's a leak, it's only 48 bytes, which in the grand scheme of things is zero. No important or sizeable object that needs to go out of existence is failing to go out of existence. Don't worry about it.